# Stress Due to Air Pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, stress-strain

Consider a pipe. The pipe is not crushed by the air pressure because the same air pressure is acting from inside the pipe. But this means that the material of the pipe is being compressed on both sides by some air pressure. So is it correct to say that the through-thickness stress in the pipe would be the same as the air pressure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, their is a compressive stress throughout the material of the pipe. However, since this stress is the same on both sides of the pipe, it is isotropic (the same in all directions) throughout the pipe and will not generate any tensile shear stresses in the pipe. Since most bulk materials are much stronger in compression than in tension, compressive stress tends not to be a cause of failure. It is the tensile shear stresses that would be generated by unequal pressures inside and outside the pipe that are a greater cause of concern.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the stress in the wall of the pipe is equall to inside/outside pressure.

Please see link below for detail:

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stress-thick-walled-tube-d_949.html

and

http://courses.washington.edu/me354a/Thick%20Walled%20Cylinders.pdf